# How to remove a line shown by clip paths on high resolutions

Tags: html, css, clip-path

After creating a clip path to mask away a part of an image leaving behind a downward pointing arrow, I get this thin line on high resolution screens or when i zoom in on a regular screen.

here is the css for the clip path:

```
.clearflowptr {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    background: white;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 46% 0, 50% 100%, 54% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
```

the `margin-bottom` and `margin-top` just add spacing to the element. I tried playing around with the `padding` but to no avail.

[image: clip-path showing line]

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one instead of using `clip-path` if its not a requirement.

```css
div{
  background-color: #0b8192;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

div:after{
  content: '';
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border: 40px solid #0b8192;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border-right-color:transparent;
  border-left-color:transparent;
  border-bottom-color:transparent;
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```